# jQuery merge loop returns?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, merge

I'm trying to get all loop results into one then using ajax to send all of them only once

Here's the code for more explanation :

```
<div class='item'>Name1</div>
<div class='item'>Name2</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".item").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
});
```

^ this returns both Name1 and Name2 but not at once, i need to merge them together so i can send them both to an ajax request

this is how i want it ( invalid code )

```
$(".item").each(function(){
  var value1 = $(this[0]).text(); // even tho i dont wanna use numbers, i wanna all of them
  var value2 = $(this[1]).text();
   var final = value1 + value2; // Name1Name2
});
    $.get('go.php', {items : final}, function(...
```

this is an invalid code ^ just to give you an example of how it should end with
first problem is merging, i don't know how it should be,
and second is i want to call **var final** from outside the loop so it wont repeat the request

Comment: What is the output string you want get?

Comment: @RoseWarad Do you want the values comma separated?

Comment: i want to use a custom output to be inside the var > var final = "Something"+value1+"Something2"+value2;

Comment: @RoseWarad OK. I think I got what you want now. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10883813/144665

Comment: @RoseWarad: I have updated my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10883824/500725](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10883824/500725)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/Wf3SF/

Try:

```
var final = [];
$(".item").each(function(){
   final.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Or:

```
var final = $('.item').map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

Or as you mentioned in your comments:

```
var items = $('.item').map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

var final = "Something1" + items[0] + "Something2" + items[1];
```

Or finally like this:

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
    window['value'+(i+1)] = this.innerHTML;
});

var final = "Something1" + value1 + "Something2" + value2;

$.get('go.php', {'items' : final }, function(...
```

Comment: can i do it inside a loop so i dont have to use numbers like items[0] / items[1]

Comment: See the last answer. Adding variables to the `window` object makes them `global` (accessible outside the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var arr =  $(".item").map(function(){
             return $(this).text();
           }).get();
```

after this `arr` will be `['Name1','Name2']`, as you want `Name1Name2` you can get that with

```
arr.join('')
```

But if you want to seperate them later it's better to join them using a delimiter like `_` or `,`. So if you want `Name1_Name2` use `.join('_')`

Then use `arr` like

```
$.get('go.php', {items : arr.join('_')}, function(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `final` outside of your function to make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').text()​​;
```

This returns `Name1Name2` as output.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Y4L5P/1/)**

### EDIT:

After looking all your comments on all answers, I understood that you might be looking for this.

```
var customTextArray = [ "AAA", "BBB" ];
var final = "";
i = 0;
$('.item').each(function() {
    final += $(this).text();
    if (customTextArray.length != i)
        final += customTextArray[i++];

});

$(".result").text(final);​
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name1AAAName2BBBName3
```

Refer to the another **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Y4L5P/2/)**

Comment: hm, well i don't think it will do what i really want because i want to separate for each of them

Comment: @RoseWarad: Have you checked the demo?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to translate all elements in the jQuery object to an array of strings.

```
var values = $(".item").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
// values = ["Name1", "Name2"]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

```
var values = $.map($(".item"), function(item) {
    return $(item).text();
});
// values = ["Name1", "Name2"]
```

Then, you can either send the values as an array to your PHP script, so you can retrieve it as a PHP array in `$_POST["items"]`.

```
$.get("go.php", {items : values}, function() { ... });
```

Or you can first join the array to a single string to receive it as a PHP string.

```
var joinedValues = values.join(",");
// joinedValues = "Name1,Name2"
$.get("go.php", {items : joinedValues}, function() { ... });
```